# Show that this equation is true.

Tags: analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations

Consider the following function in $\mathbb{R}^n (n\geq 3)$:
\begin{equation}
H(y)=2b_n\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\ as}D_n\Phi(y-\tilde{x}+bs)\text{ d} s,\quad (x, y\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}, x\neq y),
\end{equation}
where

- $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution of Laplace's equation,
- $x\equiv (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is fixed in $\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\vert\ x_n>0\}$,
- $D_n=\frac{\partial}{\partial y_n}$,
- $\tilde{x}=(x_1,\dots, x_{n-1}, -x_n)$,
- $b$ is a constant unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $b_n>0$ and $a\leq 0$.

Defining 
\begin{equation}
\xi\equiv\frac{y-\tilde{x}}{\vert y-\tilde{x}\vert},
\end{equation}

I would like to show:
\begin{equation}
2b_n\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\ as}D_n\Phi(y-\tilde{x}+bs)\text{ d} s=\vert y-\tilde{x}\vert^{2-n}\left[\frac{2b_n}{n\alpha(n)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ e^{\ a\vert y-\tilde{x}\vert s}\frac{(\xi_n+b_ns)}{\vert \xi+bs\vert^n}\text{ d}s\right]
\end{equation}

Comment: No, x is given and fixed in the upper half space.

Comment: thx, missed that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe I didn't see this but it's essentially integration by substitution with $s=\vert y-\tilde{x}\vert u$ to obtain the expression on the RHS in terms of $u$ which we can relabel in terms of $s$ as the variable which we are integrating with respect to.